# Translate the labels in xbl component

Tags: orbeon, xbl

I have a form built with Form Builder, containing an XBL component that is a little form with just xforms labels and inputs. I want to display the form (and by the way the component) in two languages (FR: French, and NL: Dutch), so in the XBL, I duplicated each label, with attributes lang="fr" and lang="nl".
But, when i run my form in Form Runner with the parameter fr-language=nl, i get all my form translated in Dutch, except the XBL component that is still in French by default.
Can you help me please if i did something wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: Finding this question again! Is this still a current issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `lang` attribute on elements is not supported by Orbeon Forms.

Orbeon Forms 4.2 features an easier way of internationalizing XBL components, see [this blog entry](http://blog.orbeon.com/2013/05/easier-localization.html).